# Loading Shell Script Files to Access Their Functions In Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a shell script file named `/path/to/shell_script.sh` which contains a function defintion `shell_function() { ...}`.

I'd like to be able to do something in Haskell like `readProcessWithExitCode shell_function [] ""` to eventually get a hold of an `IO (String)`.

How to do this?

Comment: This question is very broad. Please give some actual code and a description of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a shell script like

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() {
    echo "foo"
}
```

you can use the [`readCreateProcess`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.4.2.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:readCreateProcess) function from the *process* package to source the script and execute the function in one go, like this:

```
module Main where

import System.Process

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- I had to put the full path of the script for it to work
    result <- readCreateProcess ((shell ". /tmp/foo.sh && foo")) ""
    print result
```

This solution assumes that the script only does things like defining functions and setting environment variables, without running undesired "effectful" code each time it is sourced.